# How ifeq from Makefile works?

Tags: makefile

I have a Makefile with content:

```
define SOME_FUNC
ifeq (n,y)
    $(warning TRUE)
else
    $(warning FALSE)
endif
endef
.PHONY: all
all:
    $(eval $(call SOME_FUNC))
```

After executing "make" command I've got following output:

```
$ make
Makefile:10: TRUE
Makefile:10: FALSE
make: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
```

I cannot explain why it happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Eval-Function):

> It’s important to realize that the `eval` argument is expanded *twice*; first by the `eval` function, then the results of that expansion are expanded again when they are parsed as makefile syntax. This means you may need to provide extra levels of escaping for “$” characters when using `eval`.

You need to double the dollars to have those `$(warning ...)` functions evaluated on interpreting `ifeq` instead of expanding `eval/call`:

```
$ cat Makefile
define SOME_FUNC
ifeq (n,y)
  $$(warning TRUE)
else
  $$(warning FALSE)
endif
endef

.PHONY: all
all:
        $(eval $(call SOME_FUNC))
```

```
$ make
Makefile:11: FALSE
make: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
```